# Connecting Grails to MS SQL using trusted Connection

Tags: sql-server, web-applications, grails, grails-orm

I have account set up on SQL Server such that it uses my Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server.

Is there a way I can set up trusted connection to connect to MS SQL in Grails.

I am using :

- Grails 2.0.1
- SQL Server 2008
- Unix

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the jTDS JDBC driver (if not, I would suggest it over the MS driver), the README.SSO file included in the jTDS distribution describes how to configure trusted/single-sign-on authentication.  There is a native DLL that needs to be made available to the JVM for SSO to work.  Note that the DLL is Windows-only, so you wouldn't be able to host your Grails app on Unix.

Another possibility would be to specify your Windows AD domain, username and password in your jTDS connection string.  See http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat specifically, the **domain** property:

> **domain**
>       Specifies the Windows domain to authenticate in. If present and the user name and password are provided, jTDS uses Windows (NTLM)
>   authentication instead of the usual SQL Server authentication (i.e.
>   the user and password provided are the domain user and password). This
>   allows non-Windows clients to log in to servers which are only
>   configured to accept Windoes authentication...